# is it okay to not wrap anything for Urine incontinence issue?

Tags: salat, incontinence

I have Urine incontinence issue, and i have heard that if i wash my private part as with as the area of my underwear that may have effected with urine drops. And if the urine drop still leaks, my prayer is still valid. My Question is, Do i have wrap my private part with tissue? because some people say that i have to do it. But I find it very annoying and disturbing. Also many a times i don't have access to tissues. And sometimes the urine drops still leak through the tissue. So Do i have to wrap it up with tissue or is it just okay to wash my private part and the parts of my underwear?

Please Answer this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to cover the parts to prevent the droplets. Some points that have been highlighted by the *fuqaha'* :

1. The prayer and other acts of worship that require wudu' (ablution) **are not abolished** due to chronic urinary incontinence.
2. It is necessary to **clean the private part** first and then **cover the parts** by wrapping it with cotton, covered with a bandage, wearing pampers or any other way so that the urine droplets can be prevented from continuing to drip.
3. As for wudu', it is necessary to **perform wudu'** immediately after the cleaning process and must be taken during each of the time of prayer.

Wallahualam.